# Ruby on Rails - Errno::EACCES in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm doing this ruby on rails tutorial - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
After doing 6.4 part, I started getting this error if I try to do anything. For I get this error when trying to see a post:

Errno::EACCES in Posts#show

```
Showing /home/user/rails/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

Permission denied - /home/user/rails/blog/tmp/cache/assets/development/sass/bd7e1cc0cf5d133ac313bf5ffa5e5d87b843522a/comments.css.scssc
  (in /home/user/rails/blog/app/assets/stylesheets/comments.css.scss)

Rails.root: /home/user/rails/blog

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__1904510075995834678_70186546148480'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"1"}
```

It shows that this line raised an error:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

And the file that shows I was denied to access (comments.css.scss), is empty, with just three comment lines. What could be wrong here? I followed tutorial guidelines, don't know what I could have done differently.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: you probably ran `rake` with a different user than you are running the rails process. you need to fix the file permissions and run it with users that share the same file permissions, aka in the same group.

Comment: Linux - Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo chmod -R 777 /home/user/rails/blog` will solve your problem.

give it a try...

Answer (score 2):

If your OS is Windows you can run this in the Windows command prompt.

```
icacls C:\User\username\rails\blog /grant Everyone:F
```